# User level access/permissions in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm running Fabcar example in Hyperledger Fabric (1.4), I want to create a user using **registerUser.js** in Fabcar example which will have only **read** access to chain code. so when I run **query.js** I should get the result of **queryAllCars**, but the same user should not be able to run invoke.js **createCar** (preventing write access to chain code).

So what should be done to implement the above scenario (without using composer)?

1. How to implement role-based access at the network level?
2. How to implement role-based access at chain code level?

I am running Fabcar app from fabric-samples using docker.

If I specify the role as a user while registering the user in **registerUser.js** in Fabcar example 
`const secret = await ca.register({ affiliation: 'org1.department1', enrollmentID: 'user1', role: 'user' }, adminIdentity);`

then this user should only be able to query the chain code, but won't be able to invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

You can controll the access for each function using the ClientIdentity of the user invoking the chaincode.

```
const ClientIdentity = require('fabric-shim').ClientIdentity;
let clientIdentity = new ClientIdentity(stub);
if (client.getMSPID() === 'user') {
  return;
}
```